# Resizing the iPython/Jupyter notebook to the browser

Tags: jupyter-notebook

For some reason my iPython notebook shrunk to less than a third of the width of my browser. Of course the menu font has shrink as well to the point I am not able to read. I have modified my custom.css file to resize the font but that's good only for the text in the cells.

Is there a way to resize the notebook so that everything fits the browser?
I use Firefox under XP and Vista.

Comment: I have the same issue for Jupyter 4.0.1. I tried setting: " .container  { width:100% !important; } " in custom/custom.css as indicated in other posts--- has no effect. Did you resolve this?